# chrome://inspect detects device but doesn't show pages or apps

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug an app on android but found out that my chrome://inspect doesn't show any apps or pages anymore for my device despite showing the device itself.

I followed multiple tutorials, search for my problem on the internet but nothing came in useful and as it used to work I don't really know where to start with this issue. I will try to give you as much informations as possible:

- I tested my build on emulator and on another phone (ungoogled rom, android 11.0) and everything worked just fine, I could see and debug the app
- USB debugging is enabled in my developer options on the phone
- my android version is 11.0
- my webview version is 92.0.4515.131.
- my build is a debug one (not production)
- I recently changed my rom (from paranoid quartz 5 to ArrowOs 11.0) but I didn't use the inspector for a while before changing, so I suspect I affects the issue but I don't know how much
- I tested it on MacOS Big Sur and ArchLinux, as well as with multiple chrome versions (eloston chromium, chrome, brave)
- When trying to inspect other pages from just chrome from my phone, nothing appears either
- The app runs with cordova

What am I missing here and is there a solution for my problem other than change rom again ?

Thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score -2):

First, try to restart adb server. It can be done with these commands on unix if adb command is available to you in terminal. If not, then on unix instead of `adb`, type path (absolute to be sure) to adb executable.

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

`adb devices`

If you can see your device in output of `adb devices` (only device ID will be visible), then try to disable ipv6 for your network. Adb server might not work properly when ipv6 is enabled on your computer. In my case, disabling ipv6 have fixed that issue and I could see 'Remote target' section (which was not visible when ipv6 was enabled) and my devices once connected.